# ArcGIS Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I am working to generate a climate classification map of Pakistan (Based on Koppen Geiger Technique), so in order to map one of the climatic zone. I want to apply the condition "1<=Tmon10<4" that indicates number of months where the temperature is above 10 degree celcius. I have monthly GeoTIFF files for AirTemperature of the whole Pakistan. and I want to apply this above written condition.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: First reclass each of 12 rasters to binary (0,1) raster, e.g. Con(thisMonth>10,1,0). Use cell statistics (sum) on output, which will give a number of months.

Comment: Yes, it was really helpful. Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome to post your own answer.